# Adding extra content to Class Based View and filtering it

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-template-filters

I've built a for-loop in my HTML template and its nearly working. The issue I'm having is its listing Matches that are apart of a different tour.

I think the way to fix this is adding a filter to the view that basically says "only pull in the matches to do with this tour" which is what I've tried to do below in the Match.objects.filter() but it isnt working and I'm not sure why.

```
class CricketCalendar(generic.ListView):
    template_name="monthly_view/cricket-monthly-view.html"
    context_object_name='cricket_monthly_view'
    queryset = CricketMonthlyView.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CricketCalendar, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Tour'] = Tour.objects.all()
        context['Match'] = Match.objects.filter(tour=self.request.Tour)
        return context
```

I have also tried the following and neither worked:

```
self.kwargs['pk']
self.kwargs['Tour']
```

Edit, forgot to add the following:

Monthly View models.py:

```
class CricketMonthlyView(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey('cricket.Tour', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
related_name='tour_name')
    match_id = models.ForeignKey('cricket.Match', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and the URLs.py:

```
url(r'^monthly-view/$', monthly_view.CricketCalendar.as_view(), name='cricket-monthly'),
```

Cricket models.py:

```
class Tour(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tier_level = models.ForeignKey('sports.Tier')
    country = CountryField()
class Match(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey('Tour', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And the HTML Template:

```
{% for match_info in cricket_monthly_view %}
 {% for tour in Tour %}
<ul>
  <li>{{tour.name}}</li>
</ul>
{% for match in Match %}
  <ul>
    <li>{{match.home_team}}</li>
    <li>{{match.away_team}}</li>
  </ul>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

{% endfor %}

Comment: There isn't enough information here. How do `CricketMonthlyView`, `Tour` and `Match` relate to each other? What is the URL pattern for the view? What does your for-loop that isn't working look like?

Comment: My bad. I updated my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great place for adding a break-point. You pretty much want to know the fields on your context, and on self. Add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` in `get_context_data`, and you'll be able to see the fields on your objects. Use `dir(obj)` and `obj.keys()` in order to see all the fields on something.

Alternatively, if you have access to the tour object in your context variable, in your template you can get its matching Matches with `tour.match_set.all`

Also, be careful about naming the context variable `Tour` with a capital T, because that's the name of your model.

Comment: tour.match_set.all worked perfectly. Thank you very much for that. I also decapitalized the context variable. I'm still getting the hang of the Python Shell, I'll read up on the break-point thing you mentioned, I think that will come in handy now I've started to build bigger projects. 

Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. A few tips to save you time in the future -- install ipython (a prettier version of python), and ipdb (a prettier version of pdb). And I don't mean this to be patronizing, but if you haven't worked through the entire Django tutorial, I highly recommend it. Django has so many built-in utilities, that it's hard to know what to use without reading a lot, but the tutorial goes a long way.